# Python Caffe cpu & gpu mode simultaneously

Tags: python, caffe

Is it possible to run Caffe in both CPU and GPU mode? I have several Caffe models, but my GPU resources are limited, so that I can't put all models into GPU memory. I want to use e.g. 3 models with GPU mode and 2 models with CPU mode, but `set_mode_cpu()` and `set_mode_gpu()` commands just switch the mode for the whole library.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you can write multiple python scripts one for each task.
In each script you can choose whether use CPU or GPU (and GPU device).
Then you can run these multiple scripts at the same time.
But run multiple tasks at one GPU card with slow down the speed severely in my experience. Good luck!